# Summary worksheet using command button

Tags: vba, excel

What is missing in this code to increment the column index in the summary sheet, each time we run the below code?

```
    Sub Worksheets_Summary()
    Dim OldSheet As Worksheet
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    Dim RwNum As Long
    Dim book As Workbook
    Set book = ThisWorkbook
    Set NewSheet = book.Worksheets("Summary")
    NewSheet.Rows("2:" & NewSheet.Rows.Count).Clear

    RwNum = 1

    For Each OldSheet In book.Worksheets
        If OldSheet.Name <> "Summary" Then
            Range("B1").Value = Now()  'Change B1
            ColNum = 1
            RwNum = RwNum + 1

            NewSheet.Cells(RwNum, 1).Formula _
        = "=HYPERLINK(""#""&CELL(""address"",'" & OldSheet.Name & "'!A1)," _
             & """" & OldSheet.Name & """)"

            For Each Cell In OldSheet.Range("B11")  
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
                NewSheet.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
                "='" & OldSheet.Name & "'!" & Cell.Address(False, False)
            Next Cell

        End If
    Next OldSheet

    NewSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit


    End With
    End Sub
```

The result should look like the summary sheet in the attached picture.
First time we run the macro: data will be displayed in Column B
Second time: in Column C
etc,..

Any Thoughts?

Update Data:

[image]

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?  Please post the code that you're having a problem with.describe what is happening.

Comment: If your problem is getting your first point to work, remove the other points from the question or else it will be closed as to broad.  Then look at your first point and work out which bit of that that you are stuck on (is it the retrieving of a piece of information from a cell in a worksheet? is it the storing of a piece of information in a worksheet? is it determining which column you want to write to? is it iterating over multiple worksheets?) and cut that point down so that it concentrates on what you are stuck on.  Then show the code you have so far.  Then we can start to help you! :)

Comment: ^^ Please [edit] your question, rather than put in comments, so the current issue is clear.

Comment: @QHarr Please check it now, and let me know if it is clear, thanks.

Comment: @YowE3K Please check it!

Comment: @JamieRiis Thanks for your feedback. Please check it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding the column number to be 1, and then incrementing it a single time to be 2, you need to set the column number to be updated based on what columns are already populated and do that calculation only once (prior to looping through your worksheets).

```
Sub Worksheets_Summary()
    Dim OldSheet As Worksheet
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    Dim RwNum As Long
    Dim book As Workbook
    Set book = ThisWorkbook
    Set NewSheet = book.Worksheets("Summary")

    'The next statement seems to be ... wrong.  Each time you run the macro it will clear
    'all the previous days' values, but your question seems to imply that the summary
    'is meant to be a storage of the value of cell B11 of your other sheets as at
    'whatever times you run the macro.
    'NewSheet.Rows("2:" & NewSheet.Rows.Count).Clear

    RwNum = 1
    ColNum = NewSheet.Cells(1, NewSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

    'No point setting the header for each sheet - just do it once
    NewSheet.Cells(1, ColNum).Value = Now()  'Change B1

    For Each OldSheet In book.Worksheets
        If OldSheet.Name <> "Summary" Then
            RwNum = RwNum + 1

            NewSheet.Cells(RwNum, 1).Formula _
        = "=HYPERLINK(""#""&CELL(""address"",'" & OldSheet.Name & "'!A1)," _
             & """" & OldSheet.Name & """)"

            'I *THINK* this next loop    
            'For Each Cell In OldSheet.Range("B11")  
            '    NewSheet.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
            '    "='" & OldSheet.Name & "'!" & Cell.Address(False, False)
            'Next Cell
            'which will generate formulas of ='UPS A'!B11 in every column of the
            'UPS A row (all of which will evaluate to the same thing)
            ' is simply intended to be
            NewSheet.Cells(rwNum, ColNum).Value = OldSheet.Range("B11").Value
        End If
    Next OldSheet

    NewSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: What if the date (MM/DD/YYYY) is already written in the "Summary" sheet on the 1st Row  as follows: on cell B1 "1/1/2018" , Cell C1 "1/2/2018" and so on. Each time we run the macro the code searches the first Row for the date of Today and store the result in the column of today's date. @YowE3k

Comment: @MKonig If the column headers already exist in the Summary sheet, then the question changes from being a "increment the column number" question to being a "find the appropriate column based on heading" question, so it would be best to post a new question.  (But try something like `ColNum = NewSheet.Rows(1).Find(Date()).Column` first - that might do it.)